# asp.net mvc not returning text from a url in a cms application

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Return type is possible in this distributed style for this url?

```
 $(function () {
    $("#Submit1").click(function () {


        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:1890/Cache/Index/1',
            type: 'POST',  
            dataType: 'text',   
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);

            }
        });
    });
});


  public string Index(int id)
  {
  return "true"; 
  }
```

Comment: Are you getting an error?  If you add an error handler to your ajax call, then you might get a bit more info.

Comment: no error coming still trigging the success which is giving empty alert

Comment: Have you tried just omitting the dataType and letting jQuery infer it?

Answer (score 1):

'text' is not a supported option for the dataType paramter.  Supported options are:

**"xml"**: Treat the response as an XML document that can be processed via jQuery.

**"html"**: Treat the response as HTML (plain text); included script tags are evaluated.

**"script"**: Evaluates the response as JavaScript and evaluates it.

**"json"**: Evaluates the response as JSON and sends a JavaScript Object to the success callback.

This is taken from here: http://docs.jquery.com/Specifying_the_Data_Type_for_AJAX_Requests